# Disassemble Asus A2500H

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair

I have an aged Asus A2500H notebook, with a broken screen and damage to the outside.
Since it has a TV-out connection, and is working good otherwise, I have it hooked up to my television as a kind of media-center to play video over LAN.

I want to remove the screen as cleanly as possible, but am having trouble opening up the laptop. I've been able to remove the (broken) hinges the screen pivots on. I've also removed any other screws I could spot, but still the casing doesn't come off and seems to be attached by yet more screws I can't access (yet).

I've been searching the web for disassemble instructions, I've found some for a number of other brands and models, but not for the Asus A2500H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disassembly of the Asus A2500H is similar to the Asus A2400, disassembly instructions [can be found here](http://members.iinet.net.au/~allanxxx/A2400/).

[image]

Comment: tss! a tiny hole posing as reset button! this did the trick, thank you

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: The link you shared is now dead.